# Is it bad to rev a diesel truck right after starting it?

Tags: engine, diesel

There's an Isuzu pickup at my work and the drivers almost always rev it after starting it up, it's really hot here too so it has no issues turning over, compared to colder environments I guess. Anyways is this bad for the pickup?

Answer (score 1):

I always give any engine 30 seconds or so to get oil pumped around.

Then, I also wait for the engine to start to get warmed up a bit - like the temperature gauge starts to move before demanding full power.

My car is on 233k now...

Answer (score 0):

Revving any engine, diesel engine for locomotives, ocean going ships with huge diesel engines, aircraft engines, car/truck/suv gasoline or diesel engines are not revved when they're cold for several reasons. All internal combustion engines need oil lubrication immediately upon startup. Oil pumps take time to pressurize the oil galleries to begin lubricating camshafts, crankshafts, lifters, etc. Engines using turbochargers also pump oil into turbocharger shafts. Since oil takes time to start lubricating moving parts, its never recommended to rev engines but allow them some warm-up idle time before racing to the first stop sign or light. Cylinders are lubricated with a thin film of oil and if  oil drains off then metal to metal contact occurs and can result in scoring, eventually leading to lowering compression from continually revving an engine after starting up. This won't happen immediately but accumulate wear until startup results in a smoking exhaust. Train engines are huge and never revved, allowed many minutes of warmup time before hauling itself and loads. The same with ship engines. No one reads of captains or shipmates revving ship engines after staring them. Formula-1 racers rev their engines because those engines take a little longer to warmup and don't idle very well when cold so revving keeps these engines from stalling. Once started up and cleared to run, racers drive off to help the engine reach operating temps at low speed before the actual race begins.

For everyday driving vehicles, revving isn't recommended right after startup. Driving immediately after starting warms up the engine faster than revving in place.

Comment: F1 engines need a high idle speed due to the cam design - they won’t idle at 800rpm like a car and that is hot or cold...

Comment: @FDryer  It's not particularly relevant to the question (or the answer) given how far removed they are from the OP is asking about but you're pretty much completely wrong about the startup/warm-up procedure for F1 power units. It's all done while the car is stationary, heck most of the warming is done before the engine is even started.

Comment: I agree about F1 cars not having 800 rpm idle. More like 2k or more since they're capable of revving to 12k rpm.  "Only once all the parameters are to the engineers' satisfaction is the engine started and then warmed up. ... This means that an F1 engine is fired up only when all the parameters of the various elements of the Power Unit are at their optimum."